# Javascript upload image preview without backend

Tags: javascript, image, preview, createobject

I am trying to preview photos. Whenever I click browse input and select image - image  appears in HTML but when I click browse again and select another picture - first picture gets deleted and replaced with new output.innerHTML. Is there a way to keep old one and keep stacking them up? I am super new to JS, been trying to find a solution for a while but everyone suggests to use PHP and upload to DB, I could do that but I've been asked to make it only with vanillaJS.

```
<form id="form" method="post" onchange="loadFile(event)">
    <label for="name">File name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Test" value="">

    <label for="description">Description:</label>
    <textarea name="" id="description" cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="Alex" value=""></textarea>

    <label for="file">Upload photo:</label>
    <input type="text" id="browse" placeholder="No file selected" disabled>
    <input type="button" value="Browse" id="loadFilesXml" onclick="document.getElementById('file').click();">
    <input type="file" style="display:none;" id="file" name="file" accept="image/*">

    <div class="flex">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Upload">
    </div>
  </form>

  <script>
     let loadFile = function(event) {
     let output = document.getElementById("gallery")
     let src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
     output.innerHTML = "<div><img src='"+src+"'></div>"
   };
  </script>
```

Comment: This question has answer already here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded

Comment: Yes it works, but only with one image.

Comment: You will have to append image, not just replace it. See the reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

Comment: Thank you very much, I fixed it with your help, was wondering if it is possible that image is added only when I click upload input?

Comment: I added the answer that will show image only when you hit upload button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```
<form id="form" method="post">
    <label for="name">File name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Test" value="">

    <label for="description">Description:</label>
    <textarea name="" id="description" cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="Alex" value=""></textarea>

    <label for="file">Upload photo:</label>
    <input type="text" id="browse" placeholder="No file selected" disabled>
    <input type="button" value="Browse" id="loadFilesXml" onclick="document.getElementById('file').click();">
    <input type="file" style="display:none;" id="file" name="file" accept="image/*">

    <div class="flex">
      <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Upload" onclick="loadFile(event);">
    </div>
  </form>

  <div id="gallery"></div>

  <script>
     let loadFile = function(event){
         let output = document.getElementById("gallery");
         let file = document.getElementById("file");
         let src = URL.createObjectURL(file.files[0]);
         //output.innerHTML = "<div><img src='"+src+"'></div>";

         var e = document.createElement('div');
         e.innerHTML = "<img src='"+src+"'></div>";
         while(e.firstChild) {
            output.appendChild(e.firstChild);
        }


   };
  </script>
```

Add css style(s) to beautify, resize as you please.

Comment: That's good, if you're satisfied by the answer, just accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I did it. Quick question, maybe you will know it, is it possible to keep images in HTML when i click back button?

Comment: When you click back button, you get previously opened page, like history back, the answer is No unless you do some additional steps JavaScript cookies etc.. thank you for accepting the answer.